# Remove SQL Server Express before installing the Developer edition

Tags: sql-server

Planning to install SQL Server Developer edition. Should I remove SQL Server Express that came with Visual Studio before installing it? Can they work together? Is there any reason not to remove SQL Server Express?

Comment: You can remove it yes. Can you run them side by side, yes. Should you? Well that's up to you. Are you going to continue to use the Express edition as well? If not, why do you need it? It'll just be using resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio installs SQL Express LocalDB, which provides on-demand SQL Instances in the user's desktop session.  The SQL Server Data Tools requires this, and it's handy also for other development and test scenarios.

Also there's no reason to remove it.

Comment: Is it possible to enable LocalDB use for remote clients via TCP/IP?

Comment: No.  LocalDB is intended for local connections only.  It may be technically possible to connect to its named pipe, but it's not a supported scenario.  For remote connections, install an instance of SQL Express using the normal installer.